# Why would sinon mock pass both once() and never() on call inside returned Promise?

Tags: javascript, mocking, mocha.js, sinon

I am new to mocha/sinon/promises.One test I wrote with mock on a function that returns a promise really confuses me. I created a complete example below, which at this point is a little contrived because I was trying to strip this down to the bare minimum that shows the issue.

```
'use strict';

const sinon = require('sinon');

var _fakeGetAndPost = {
    get: (cmd, cb) => cb("", cmd),
    post: (cmd, cb) => cb("", cmd) 
};


function getCardsFromList(specificGetCardsCmd) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        _fakeGetAndPost.get(specificGetCardsCmd, (err, response) => {
            if (err) {
                 reject(err);
            } else {
                resolve(response);
            }
        });
    });
}

describe("Experiment with mock", () => {

    it("The mock passes with both once() and never() - but shouldn't", () =>        {
        var myMock = sinon.mock(_fakeGetAndPost);
        myMock.expects('get').once(); //never() also passes, /twice() fails
        getCardsFromList("junk");
        myMock.verify();
        myMock.restore();
    });

});
```

The confusion arises from the `myMock.expects('get').once();` line. If I replace the expectation of `once()` with `twice()` the test fails as expected. However, if I replace `once()` with `never()` the code **still passes**. I was surprised by this and don't understand how or why this can happen. If `twice()` had also passed I would have suspected that mocha wasn't waiting for the promise but since `twice()` fails it looks like that mechanism works.

Comment: I wouldn't use Sinon at all here. What you are doing is testing the internals (which makes your test brittle - if you refactor your internals, you have to fix your test). What you should be doing is testing the result. For example, you can do:
return getCardsFromList("junk")
  .then((result) => {
    // assert the result.
  });

Comment: I greatly simplified what I was doing here for the post. If I don't use sinon won't _fakeAndGetPost.get() actually fire? To clarify in real life what I'm calling fakeAndGetPost.get() is a call to the Trello API. I don't want my tests to depend on the Trello API, so I'm mocking them out. I have other logic in this method. Sometimes the get happens sometimes it does not. That is what I want to test. Given some conditions the call should happen once. In other conditions is should not happen.